# bash: seq 1 4 | shuf > output.csv

Tags: bash, csv

With the following command I get a csv file with a randomized sequence.

```
seq 1 4 | shuf > output.csv
```

However, there is an empty line in the file at the end when opening the file with Sublime Text 2.

How to avoid having that empty line?

Comment: I tried this but do not get any empty lines. Are you seeing the empty line even if you do `cat` or `vi` of the file?

Comment: @Vasan I don't see the empty line at the end when opening with cat or vi but I see it when opening the file with Sublime Text 2 and it also becomes apparent by processing the file further (paste -d "," input1.csv input2.csv > output.csv) to add two files line by line.

Comment: found a solution here: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206918/… paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv | tr -d '\r' > paste.csv

Answer (score 1):

An empty line is part of the Unix standard or it would rather print
`1,2,3,4user@localhost:$` on cat.
You may convert it directly to CSV with the same SEQ command:

```
seq -s ', ' 1 5
```

Should output
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
You can also remove the last ", " (with space) using

```
seq -s ', ' 1 5|rev | cut -c 3- | rev
```

If you use just ",", without a space, you might change -c 3 to -c 2

```
seq -s ',' 1 5|rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```

It would output `1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: I would like to combine two cvs files like by line later. Currently I am using paste -d "," input1.csv input2.csv > output.csv for that. Therefor I was looking for a way to get the random sequence each number in a new line.

Comment: Found a solution here found a solution here: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206918/… paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv | tr -d '\r' > paste.csv